# Windows 10 BSOD freeze after sleep + blue screen on boot

Tags: windows-10, crash, bsod, sleep, thinkpad

## I had the following problem:

I just fresh installed Windows 10 on my ThinkPad t450s and crashed after every sleep.

When the laptop is in sleep mode and I open it and press a key to wake it up:

- BSOD appears directly saying "Your PC ran into a problem and needs a restart. We're just collecting some error info, and then we'll restart for you. (0% complete) - [...] CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED";
- OR login screen appears but everything is laggy and then the BSOD appears;
- OR once I've got as far as the desktop using the fingerprint device, but then the BSOD appeared, this time without the error name.

Never did the percentage change from 0% before the computer rebooted.

I updated the graphic card drivers and the Wi-Fi drivers, deactivated the quick boot and tried many bizarre suggestions from the internet, but nothing helped.

## Now since the last sleep crash:

The computer doesn't work at all, it shows an empty blue screen after each startup.

I tried to repair Windows using the Windows 10 USB stick, but it fails to find anything wrong or to restore a previous build.

I found [this post suggesting to delete a driver](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-power/windows-10-blue-screen-on-boot/2715181c-edc9-498f-aa69-76263a5a1086?auth=1) but I don't know how to do it as my drive is encrypted using BitLocker and the command prompt is telling me to use to control panel to unlock it.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same, stupid windows 10, I wanna use it but it's giving me heads.